# Setting AlternatingRowBackground for DataGrid with Templated DataGridRow

Tags: wpf, datagrid, styling

I need to have DataGrid with black and dark gray rows. By default it would have gray rectangle in the left of each row (marked by red in screenshot) which I don't need. To remove it I have to use Template for DataGridRow. The problem I get is that AlternatingRowBackground wouldn't work in that case, though I tried to set Background="Transparent" for Border and DataGridCellsPresenter. I found example with VisualStates but this code seems very heavy. Is there neat way to fix it?

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                    <Border>
                        <DataGridCellsPresenter/>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
        <Setter Property="Background"
                Value="Black" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground"
                Value="White" />
        <Setter Property="RowBackground"
                Value="Black" />
        <Setter Property="AlternatingRowBackground"
                Value="DarkGray" />
    </Style>
```

[image: screens]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gray rectangle is the so called row Header. By default the DataGrid turns on row and column header. You turn it off the row header by setting

```
HeadersVisibility=Column
```

So, you don't need a template to get that done.